# sonar-project.properties doesnt seem to be picked up when trying to Run SonarScanner from the Docker image

Tags: docker, sonarqube, docker-image, sonarscanner

I have been trying to do the "Running SonarScanner from the Docker image" from the documentation"

```
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /opt/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarScanner 4.6.0.2311
INFO: Java 11.0.11 AdoptOpenJDK (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 5.10.25-linuxkit amd64
INFO: User cache: /opt/sonar-scanner/.sonar/cache
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /opt/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 8.8.0
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=63ms
INFO: Server id: BF41A1F2-AXkMJHXiUF2U87mzcajk
INFO: User cache: /opt/sonar-scanner/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load/download plugins
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=35ms
INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=1086ms
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 2.438s
INFO: Final Memory: 5M/20M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
ERROR: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

my guess is that the sonar-project.properties are not being picked up and I don't understand why not

```
docker run \
--rm \
--network=host \
-e SONAR_HOST_URL="http://127.0.0.1:9000/" \
-e SONAR_LOGIN="*token*" \
-v $(pwd)/idevops-crmservice:/root/src \
sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli
```

when I try to searching for this issue, all I really get is to use

```
sonar-runner -Dsonar.projectKey=
```

but that does not help me since I need the sonar-project.properties to be picked up

im wanting to scan an entire folder and unsure on what to do.

Comment: what is the contents of your sonar-scanner.properties?

Comment: > sonar.projectKey=idevops-crmservice
sonar.projectName=idevops-crmservice
sonar.projectVersion=1.0 
sonar.language=py
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.host.url=http://127.0.0.1:9000/
sonar.login=admin 
sonar.password=admin
sonar.projectBaseDir=/home/alexis

Answer (score 1):

I also have same problem. and the solution is either dont run it on docker.. or create a new docker myself. the docker image on its documentation doesnt provide any argument other than the sample that was given.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the `docker run` command while inside your project's root folder? if so, you don't need to add `$(pwd)/<project-folder>`, just `$(pwd)`.